# linq to SQL category sub category count Recursive

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

**product**

ID
CategoryID
Name
...

**Category**
ID
ParentCategoryID
Name

Product > CategoryID  = foreign key

```
public class NameIDCount
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}
    public int Count { get;set;}
}

public class NameIDCountList
    {
        public NameIDCount _Category { get; set; }
        public List<NameIDCount> _SubCategories { get; set; }
    }
```

How do

Linq Query?

`List<NameIDCountList> NameIDCountList =` LINQ ?

Result:

```
<a href="/category/id=1">PC [23]</a>
    <a href="/category/id=4">NoteBook [2]</a>
    <a href="/category/id=5">Desktop [21]</a>
<a href="/category/id=2">Monitor [6]</a>
     <a href="/category/id=8">LED Monitor [4]</a>
     <a href="/category/id=9">LCD Monitor [2]</a>
```

Comment: did you try to groupby name and use the aggregate `count` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        var nameidlist = new List<NameIDCount>
        {
            new NameIDCount{ID=1,Name="PC", Count =1},
            new NameIDCount{ID=2,Name="PC", Count =1},
            new NameIDCount{ID=3,Name="PC", Count =1},
            new NameIDCount{ID=4,Name="Monitor", Count =1}
        };

        var nl = new List<NameIDCount>();

        nameidlist.GroupBy(x => x.Name, p => p.ID).ToList().ForEach((y) =>
        {
            nl.Add(new NameIDCount { Count = y.ToList().Count, Name = y.Key });
        });
```

Comment: even if you use this kind of linq query in EF, there will be no issue, it will be transformed to SQL prior to hitting the db. If not, please explain the performance issue you have reported earlier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509527/linq-to-sql-category-sub-category-count-performans